# MongoDB, ObjectId's Array not recognized as array when using $nin

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to match documents based on the fact that their _id is not present in ObjectId's Array of their own.

Mongodb version: 3.2

Here's my query :

```
db.subscriptions.aggregate(
[
    { $match : { "device": { $exists: true } } },
    { 
      $lookup : { 
            from: "devices",
            localField: "device",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "device"
        } 
    },
    { $match : { "device.0" : { $exists: true } } },
    { $unwind: "$device" },
    { $project : {"_id": 1, "subs": "$device.subscriptions" } },
    { $match: { "_id": { $in: this.subs } } }
]
)
```

I have two collection subscriptions and devices.
The document subscription have a property device which is an ObjectId refering to a device. The device document have an array of objectId refering to the subscriptions. It's a one-to-many relationship.

Step 1:
Matching subscription who actualy have the device property (it's not a clean clean db)

Step 2:
I'm performing a lookup to get my device document inside the subscription

Step 3:
Once again matching the fact that the lookup did give result

Step 4:
Unwind the device cause the lookup thing give me an array (i dont quite understand why tho')

Step 5:
Projecting the subscriptions array and the subscription id to work with simpler document:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("587e265cb9b235243c7f9960"), 
    "subs" : [
        ObjectId("5899a894b1e11521a44a96f7"), 
        ObjectId("5a8c494db0bed60b389cb1da")
    ]
}
```

Step 6:
This is where the error appear, mongo's teling me this.subs is not an array so i cant use $nin =>  "errmsg" : "$in needs an array"

I've tried multiple format: "this.subs", "$subs", none of that works.

Can somebody helps me ?

Théo

Comment: what is the result when you remove the last query in pipeline and add the result in your question?
because I am unable to make sense without data.

Comment: You can see step 5 my result. I get these kind of documents when i'm removing the last $match. @Veeram answer was the one. Thanks nonetheless for you reply !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below aggregation in 3.2. You can't compare the document field in [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) stage. So you have to create a intermediate field (cmp) to hold the result from such comparison and $match stage to compare the result. Also there is no $in ( aggregation operator ). You have to use [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) to mimic such comparisons.

```
db.subscriptions.aggregate(
  [
    previous stages stages until $unwind
    {$project:{
      add all the fields you want in response,
      "cmp":{$not:{$setIsSubset: [["$_id"], "$device.subscriptions"]}}
    }},
    {$match: {"cmp": true}}
  ]
)
```

Upgrade to 3.4 you can use [`$in(aggregation)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator and below pipeline.

```
db.subscriptions.aggregate(
  [
    previous stages stages until $unwind
    {$project:{
      add all the fields you want in response,
      "cmp":{$not:{$in: ["$_id", "$device.subscriptions"]}}
    }},
    {$match: {"cmp": true}}
  ]
)
```

Upgrade to 3.6 you can use [`$in(aggregation)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) operator inside the `$match` with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) which lets you use aggregation operators.

```
db.subscriptions.aggregate(
  [
    previous stages stages until $unwind
    {$match: {"$expr": {$not:{$in: ["$_id", "$device.subscriptions"]}}}}
  ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Your answer was perfect. I've only tested the 3.2 version so far but i'm glad you added all of them. I might upgrade my db version in the near futur.